# Запрет на создание приватного репозитория GitHub

Tags: github, repository, account

Проблема заключается в том, что гитхаб не дает установить статус "Приватного" для любого из репозиториев, которые созданы на моем аккаунте.

Цитата: **"Change repository visibility:
Due to restrictions on this repository, you cannot change the visibility."**

Не до конца понятно, что за ограничения репозитория и почему эти ограничения у всех репозиториев на аккаунте. А самый главный вопрос: как их снять?

Comment: может быть у вас недостаточно прав на эту операцию. т.е. не у репозитория, а конкретно у пользователя... вот пример с организацией https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-organization-settings/restricting-repository-visibility-changes-in-your-organization

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Думаю, вполне может такое быть. Только я не совсем понимаю из-за чего мой аккаунт мог получить такое ограничение, и что нужно сделать, чтобы его убрать. Информации в сети по этому вопросу я не нашел.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то приватными можно сделать репозитории только у платных аккаунтов.

Comment: @ВикторКарев сейчас (c 2019/01/07), по дефолту, приватные репозитории на гитхабе можно делать всем.